# Can I freeze an application to run it at a later time?

Tags: ram, hibernate

Though it might seem silly, I want to freeze an application that I can not save my progress in (specifically games where I have to play a full level, and time is short sometimes but I still would love to play in 10 min sessions).

Is there a way to freeze an application, something like place RAM into a file **and close it**, and later **especially after a reboot** run that application again with the RAM it had when I saved it.

I am thinking of how Ubuntu can hibernate (since it stores all application ram to disk) and when it wakes from hibernation all apps have the RAM used in session prior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
kill -SIGSTOP $(pgrep process_name)
```

to suspend a process and

```
kill -SIGCONT $(pgrep process_name)
```

to resume it.

In terminal the shorthand would be:
Ctrl+Z to suspend and fg to bring it back into forground, bg to make it continue in background.

Comment: Thank you, but i wish to close the application after freezing it, and run it later, **especially after a reboot**

Comment: The problem (also with my solution) is that most modern applications interact with each other and are really likely to crash.

Comment: Ah, here's maybe an answer (although they mention those problems too): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134771/hibernate-a-process-in-linux